# How can we implement LightGBM in Weka?

Tags: weka, lightgbm

Hope you are well

By default, Weka does not include LightGBM.

Is there any way to implement LightGBM in Weka?

Answer (score 0):

Since, LightGBM has a [sklearn module](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/lightgbm/sklearn.html), you might be able to reuse/adapt the [wekaPython package](https://weka.sourceforge.io/packageMetaData/wekaPython/), as it provides integration with sklearn algorithms.